# Maintain scheduled action after record is updated

Tags: process-builder, time-dependent-workflow, scheduled-action

I'm using process builder to fire a scheduled action with the following criteria:

```
AND
(
TEXT([Opportunity].Status__c) <> "Open",
PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].Status__c) = "Open"
)
```

the scheduled action is set to fire 1 hour after the last modified date. When I ran the process it showed up in the waiting and paused interviews section and it updated the field value I was expecting. However, after some more tests, I noticed that the waiting flow was removed if I changed another field value since the status was not equal to "Open" but the prior value would no longer be "Open" so it removed the waiting interview.

How can I get around that? I want the flow to remain the in queue to fire after the hour while the record is modified during that hour time frame?

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria is incorrect. Simply use "Status__c equals open". This way, as long as the status remains open, the action will remain scheduled. You might also want to change the trigger time from one hour after last modified to one hour after rule trigger, although without knowing your intent, I can't say for certain.

Comment: the goal is to schedule the action when the status moves from "open" to another value. If I run it when the status is just "open" it will be scheduled incorrectly. Is there a way to capture when that status is changed from "open" to another value and  schedule the action? Also, in PB it doesn't have the option to first after rule trigger or at least I don't see it. Am I missing that option, should it be there in process builder?

Comment: @Dman100 Use the "advanced" option on the filter step, and it will fire only when the status moves to Open. that's how you're supposed to do it.